# Internal server error when trying to enable webhook integration for messager bot

Tags: heroku, bots

I am following this tutorial: https://blog.hartleybrody.com/fb-messenger-bot/

All works fine, I cloned the data and opened a heroku website. Only when I try to enable webhook integration and I add the website address i get:

```
The url couldnt be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: HTTP Status Code = 500; HTTP Message = INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are still at it, there is one step you missed:

> - Verification Token - A secret value that will be sent to your bot, in order to verify the request is coming from Facebook. Whatever value you set here, make sure you add it to your Heroku environment using heroku config:add VERIFY_TOKEN=your_verification_token_here

so, you need to provide to facebook the verification token you configure in this step `heroku config:add VERIFY_TOKEN=your_verification_token_her`

Answer (score 0):

make sure your access tokens are webhook url are correct. If those are correct but, you are still getting errors. Then you check out the logs from heroku. In your CMD if you're using windows, type: heroku logs. Heroku will give logs of all your code as well as any errors that may be there. If you have an error in your code correct it and try again. Everything should work after that. Good luck.